# How to show image with blurred background via Glide in Android?

Tags: android, android-glide

Goal is effectively show image in center with blurred background in `ImageView` via `GLide`.
Maximum height of image is 200dp.

[image: Goal]

Temp. solution:
I have two `ImageView`'s that are overlaping (first bottom `ImageView` has: `android:scaleType="fitXY"`):

```
//Blurred background
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/previewBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

//Center image
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

Two `Glide`'s:

Create and Show blur background:

```
Glide.with(mCtx)
    .load(Uri.fromFile(file))
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    .transform(new BlurTransformation(25, 3))
    .into(previewBackground);
```

Show center image:

```
Glide.with(mCtx)
    .load(Uri.fromFile(file))
    .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
    .placeholder(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
    .into(preview);
```

Gradle:

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:4.1.0' //to use BlurTransformation
```

**Problems**:
The background and center image loads in different time, because there is using of two GLides.
Probably bad effectivity.

I tried solution with one `Glide` and one `ImageView`:
`.into(new CustomTarget<Drawable>() {...}`, but there is problem with GLide does not know `ImageView` size, and `placeholder` and `transition` does not work.

next tried `ImageViewTarget`:

```
.into(new ImageViewTarget<Drawable>(preview) { //Have to be ImageViewTarget for placeholder and transition working
    @Override
      protected void setResource(@Nullable Drawable resource) {
        //preview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        preview.setBackground(resource);
      }
})
```

`placeholder` and `transition` working well, but blurred background does not show, because blurred background width is the same as center image. When I use `preview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);` center image fills all possible width. I need show image to the center with width and maxHeight 200dp and blurred background stretch to maximum width and maxHeight 200dp.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

this code is working for me try this with picaso 2.5.2

public class BlurTransformation implements Transformation {
RenderScript rs;

```
public BlurTransformation(Context context) {
    super();
    rs = RenderScript.create(context);
}

@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap bitmap) {
    // Create another bitmap that will hold the results of the filter.
    Bitmap blurredBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    // Allocate memory for Renderscript to work with
    Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, blurredBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_FULL, Allocation.USAGE_SHARED);
    Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());

    // Load up an instance of the specific script that we want to use.
    ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
    script.setInput(input);

    // Set the blur radius
    script.setRadius(10);

    // Start the ScriptIntrinisicBlur
    script.forEach(output);

    // Copy the output to the blurred bitmap
    output.copyTo(blurredBitmap);

    bitmap.recycle();

    return blurredBitmap;
}

@Override
public String key() {
    return "blur";
}
```

}